# How to put several nRF24L01 adapters (+module) on a breadboard?

Tags: components, breadboard, adapter, nrf24l01

I want to use several nRF radios together with an adapter like this:

[image]

Also, for the device I'm using these for (two nRF's) also I have other components which I put on a breadboard.

However, the nRF adapter does not have pins so I cannot stick it in a breadboard, but I want to keep it together. I don't like two nRF's dangling when I move the breadboard for example. Also, there does not need to be a connection from the nRFs to the breadboard.

Is there some smart idea how to connect such adapter to a breadboard? Glueing to the breadboard is not an option, since I want to reuse the breadboard.
I was thinking about glueing it to IC sockets and stick them in unused holes in the breadboard but those sockets are not meant for breadboard... I can use tape maybe, but probably I'm not the first one having this 'problem' and there are better ideas.

Comment: I did come across this version of the adapter board. http://arduino-for-beginners.blogspot.co.uk/p/nrf-adapter-for-sale.html

Comment: @JImDearden That is indeed nice, however, cost ($10 shipping cost) make it a bit much for something like that (assuming I have already 5 in possession and bought 5 new ones for about $1,50).

Glueing them on a cheap IC would be cheaper, or glueing some plastic between two sets of pin headers and glue the adapter on top of it :-)

Comment: The main reason for using the header board was you need the current at 3v3.  Have a look at http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/10pcs-AMS1117-3-3V-3-3V-800mA-3pin-Step-down-Power-Supply-Module-/272486527579?hash=item3f7176725b:g:luoAAOSw8-tWYPEI as an alternative to using a header board.

Comment: @Jim Dearden True .. and possible some capacitors. But I already have those adapters ... tomorrow when I'm home I'm going to check if I can use an IC with some tape/elastic or glue (DIP8 ICs like 74HC595N cost like 5 cents)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put this as answer to maybe bring others with the same 'problem' to this idea (or not).

I think the pictures are speaking for themselves.

Some remarks:

- I haven't checked if the elastics will bother the PCB antenna
- It is not 100% stable while inserting wires but after that it stays quite well (depending on the strength/length of the elastics of course)
- I used 74HC595N ... make sure no metal is pressed (in my case no problem). Otherwise use isolation tape.
- The 74HC595N only performs as 'base', it does not make any (useful) electronic contact with both the breadboard and the RF (adapter).

Cost for 74HC595N: about 5 cents?

Advantages:

- 74HC595N are reusable
- Reasonable stable (after wiring)

Disadvantages:

- It is cheap ... it looks also cheap

[[image: Picture 1]
[[image: Picture 2]]